# JSON Codable Swift 4 "None" type

Tags: json, swift

In response to the query, the answer "error" comes to me: None, I can not cope with assigning it to a given type. Maybe someone has a solution or an idea how to bypass this value.

My code:

```
import Foundation

struct Test: Codable {
let id: Int
let error: ???????

}

let json = """
{"error": None,
"id": 1
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let product = try decoder.decode(Test.self, from: json)

print(product.id)
```

Comment: The bare string `None` is not valid JSON, so you're not going to be able to parse this with any JSON parser. Are you sure you can't fix whatever is generating this data to produce valid JSON?

Comment: Did you mean `null` instead of `None`?

Answer (score 0):

First, The struct doesn't properly conform to the protocols required -> See Below.

Second to throw the error from the decoder you should try to do this;

```
do {
    try decoder.decode()
    // handle data here
} catch {
// handle error
}
```

Third, your error constant could be many things. `Error()`, `NSError()`, a custom object... If you make the `error` of type `Error()` and the value is nothing, you'll want to do an `if let` statement to catch a nil value and not allow the value be "None". For example:

```
var theError = nil
if let error = myError {
    // because you hard coded the value of error to be "None" return nil instead
    // else return the actual value of the error
    if error == "None" { return theError } else {
        theError = error
        print("error has a value! ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
} else {
     print("There is no error")
}

return theError // returns nil instead of "None" or it returns a real error
```

[image: Codable Protocol]

Comment: Then if you use the encoder it should automatically update the value of nil to a JSON equivalent.